# Oracle for Hamming distance to a secret bitvector

Tags: boolean-functions, lg.learning

Let $s \in \{0,1\}^n$ be a secret bitvector.  Define $f(x)$ to be the Hamming distance between $x$ and $s$.   Suppose I am given an oracle for $f$, and I want to find $x$.  How many queries to the oracle are needed to determine $x$?  I want an algorithm that is efficient (running time polynomial in $n$, say).  I am fine with average-case complexity (over a uniform distribution on $s$).

Information theoretically, $\Theta(n/\lg n)$ randomly chosen queries $x_i$ should suffice, but I can't think of any efficient algorithm to recover $s$ from the values of $f(x_i)$.  Obviously $s$ can be efficiently recovered given $n$ queries or so.  How much better can we do?

Comment: See [my answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/81739/683) to the same question on [cs.se].